# Show Image in a new window with a unique ID on grid view button click in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm a newbie to asp.net or should say web applications. I'm working on grid view in which I want to show an image on button click event in a new window with a unique URL.

I have a grid view in which I'm handling a button click event like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "LinkID")
    {           
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow _gridrow = GridView1.Rows[index];
        String _strlink = "http://www.abcd.com/offers.aspx?id=";
    }
 }
```

I want this to pass this string to the second form to show the image that I'm having on a local path like `~/Images/abc.jpg`

IF you have any idea ,Please share your experience.

Comment: you shd share even if we dont have idea, it will help others who can aswer your query

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (e.CommandName == "LinkID") {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            string id = _gridrow.DataKeys(index)("ID").ToString();
            Response.Redirect("http://www.abcd.com/offers.aspx?id=" + id);
}
```

Comment: string id = _gridrow.DataKeys(index)("ID").ToString();  

"ID" - field name from your table